# Error during AST class visiting

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am trying to run a spring mvc in a tomcat server. When I try to run the code,in the Error Log Page of Eclipse IDE, am getting this error Error during AST class viting and the plugin is mentioned as org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core. I am not getting this error in console or in Markers view. Its displayed in Error Log.

Please suggest me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "Java builder" is above the "Spring builder" in the builder part of your project. If not the spring builder will try to visit classes not yet compiled.

Comment: Java Builder is already above Spring Builder, Still error is there. Any other ideas?